# Delete empty csv files in directory - R

Tags: r, csv

I have many csv files in a folder (1.csv,2.csv....,20.csv) but a few of them are empty (5.csv,8.csv). The empty files even contain a size around 4 bytes and are not size 0. 

I need to delete them in the directory and I want to achieve this in R. Is this possible? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `countLines()` from `R.utils` package does the job:

```
library(R.utils)

lapply(Filter(function(x) countLines(x)==0, list.files(pattern='.csv')), unlink)
```

Comment: It worked! Applied countlines(x)<=1 as the empty files were giving the output for countLines(empty files) as 1.

Comment: Great, happy to help. countLines is a usefull function to turn around the issue of the 4 bytes (you can have some lines in a 4 bytes csv!)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
setwd("/path/to/files/")   #set the directory
for(i in list.files(pattern="*.csv$"))  # iterate i over .csv files
if(file.info(i)$size==0) remove.file(i)  #delete the ones with 0 length
#or
if(R.utils::countLines(i)==0) remove.file(i) #delete the ones with 0 lines.
```

Comment: Hey! it didn't work. The file size is not 0. It shows as 4 bytes.

Comment: Use `countLines()==0` or set a `<=4` limit