# Skip or ignore empty csv files in directory - R

Tags: r, csv

I have a bunch of `csv` files in a directory.  Some of the files are empty.  I can delete the empty files using the following code:

[Delete empty csv files in directory - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410695/delete-empty-csv-files-in-directory-r)

```
setwd('C:/Users/mmiller/Documents/simple R programs/')
my.folder <- paste0(getwd(), '/', 'empty_csv_files/')
setwd(my.folder)
my.delete.empty.csv = lapply(Filter(function(x) countLines(x)==0, list.files(pattern='.csv')), unlink)
my.model.files <- list.files(my.folder, pattern="^model.*?\\.csv")
my.model.list  <- lapply(paste0(my.folder, my.model.files), read.csv)
my.model.data  <- do.call(rbind, my.model.list)
```

However, this code physically removes (i.e., destroys) empty `csv` files from a directory.  Is there a way to simply skip or ignore the empty `csv` files instead of destroying them?  I feel a little uncomfortable destroying files because that seems to eliminate a clear and ready record of all steps taken.  I might not readily know exactly how many files were destroyed, for example.

Here are the contents of the files I used in this example (`model3.csv` was empty):

```
model1.csv
var1
1
2
3

model2.csv
var1
10
20
30

model3.csv

model4.csv
var1
100
200
300

model5.csv
var1
1000
2000
3000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `file.size` to test which files have length zero and skip those.

```
CSV_Files = dir(pattern="*.csv")
CSV_Files[file.size(CSV_Files) > 0]
```